# Citing/Referring: How to have a \parencite without bracket ( )?

Tags: biblatex

How can I have a reference without a `( )`  and with `( )`?

For example:

```
1. Table 1: Spich et al, 2010

A text is written by (Spich et al, 2010).
```

Should I create another name instead of using the same `\parencite`?

My MWE:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Comment: *Usually* (in the `biblatex` standard styles without modifications that say otherwise, that is), `\cite` gives the result that `\parencite` would give you, just without the parentheses. If you have custom code that results in different output, you need to share an MWE with us. Not having seen any code, you could simply take a copy of the code you show, use a different name like `\nparencite` and drop the `[\mkbibparens]`, but there may be much more elegant ways to do this.

Comment: @moewe. Thanks a lot. It works. I created a different name like `\nparencite` and drop the `[\mkbibparens]`. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `\textcite`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually (e.g. in the `biblatex` standard styles without modifications that say otherwise), `\cite` gives the result that `\parencite` would give you, just without the parentheses.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \parencite{sigfridsson}
dolor \cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) ipsum (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) dolor Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998]

So the first thing I would try is `\cite`.

Without having seen your code I can't tell if that will work as you hoped it would, though. It is hard to say what the most elegant way to achieve the result you want to see is in your setup, but the following should work provided the definition of `\parencite` from the question does the right thing. You can simply copy the definition of `\parencite`, give it a new name and drop the `[\mkbibparens]`, which produces the parentheses.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\nparencite}
  {\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[381]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \parencite[382]{sigfridsson}
dolor \nparencite[383]{sigfridsson}
sit \cite[384]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998: p. 381) ipsum (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998: p. 382) dolor Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998: p. 383 sit Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, p. 384]